# Laravel 5.2: Undefined class form

Tags: php, composer-php, phpstorm, laravel-5, laravelcollective

I have a problem with using Form command in a Composer + Laravel 5.2 project with PhpStorm as IDE.

I'm using Laravel Collective 5.2. in my `composer.json`, so it should work. (sadly, it's not which is the reason I'm here...)

The providers:

```
Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider::class,
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

my aliases.

```
'Form'      => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html'      => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

The problem: It's returned as a undefined class when I'm using `{!! Form::close() !!}` or any form command in my `blade.php`.

Did I misunderstood something when I installed it in the project? 
What do I need to configure in order for this to work?

And yes, I have looking around on forums. 
The answers didn't help because they were for Laravel 4 or Laravel 5.1. :S

Comment: Did you try to `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan cache:clear` ?

Comment: @stephenthedev Yeah. It did nothing. :T Still same after I "fired" these two command in terminal.

Comment: The issue is probably from the package. You can report it as issue here: https://github.com/LaravelCollective/laravelcollective.com/issues

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually i'm not even mad that's amazing because I found a solution to my problem... just around 5 min after I post my question... And I spend around 2 hours to find a solution...

All I did was:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan ide-helper:generate
php artisan optimize
```

and reload the `blade.php`.

I have no idea why, but it works now.
It seems I forgot to run the above commands after I got Laravel Collective 5.2 in the project. This could be the reason that form command didn't work. .___.;;

I hope someone could use this information for their own project.

Comment: This works in phpstorm. Thanks!!! Tried whole day for fixing this error. :)

Comment: `php artisan optimize` has been removed on Laravel 5.6

Answer (score 2):

You can get full solution about form builder in Laravel 5.2.

Run command prompt and execute

1. composer require laravelcollective/html
2. Open `config/app.php`  In `providers` array add `Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class` and in `aliases` array add

> ```
> ‘Form’ => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
> ‘Html’ => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class
> ```

For more details, See there   http://laraveldeveloper.me/form-in-laravel-5-2