# Laravel 5.2, LaravelCollective 5.2, Class 'Html' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, illuminate-container, laravelcollective

I followed these steps but still getting "Html" class not found.

added in `composer.json`

```
"require": {
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"
}
```

once installed, added these lines in `config/app.php`

```
  'providers' => [
    // ...
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
  ],

  'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

please see attached screen shot. what can be the reason, I also tried `composer dump-autoload` `composer clear-cache` but it didn't resolve the issue

[image]

**Updated**

View sample code

```
{!!Html::style('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')!!}
{!!Html::style('assets/css/custom.css')!!}

{!!Html::script('assets/js/jquery.min.js')!!}
{!!Html::script('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js')!!}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "once installed"? Did you run `composer update`?

Comment: can u show the view file also ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.1: Class html does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350030/laravel-5-1-class-html-does-not-exist)

Comment: @patricus its not duplicate, as I asked for Laravel 5.2 version and your mentioned link is for Laravel 5.1, so not duplicate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found the solution here, its worked perfectly.

**Followed these steps**

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```

it will install `html` & `form` as per your installed Laravel version (**mine 5.2**)

**Added Providers and Aliases**

Open `config/app.php`  In `providers` array add

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class
```

and in `aliases` array add

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class
```

---

**Found solution here**

---

> http://laraveldeveloper.me/form-in-laravel-5-2/

Stackoverflow

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/35169836/1216451
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/34807375/1216451

Comment: What is different between the solution posted here and what you said you'd already done in your question?

Comment: there is miner difference while adding package in `composer.json` and running `composer require` command it added some different version

Comment: I don't believe that would have had anything to do with your issue. I see you updated your question to correct the casing in your blade code. Was that a typo in your question, or were you using `HTML` in all caps?

Comment: OK, as I suspected, you added it to `composer.json` but you didn't actually *install* it via `composer update`. `composer require` basically does an update behind the scenes.

Comment: @patricus I am still getting same error on windows plate farm (Windows 10) `Class Html not found` do you have an suggestion ?

Comment: @patricus although when I made fresh Laravel installation and then install the `laravelcollective/html` that is working fine